Как подключиться по ssh через wsl debian к manjaro на ноутбуке?
Всем привет. Я не давно установил manjaro на новый ноутбук. Я словил на мысле, что будет круто, если буду управлять ноутбуком через ssh на ПК по ssh в wsl. Искал в интернете ответы. Ну вот получилось, но при попытке подключение к ноутбуку идет долгая попытка подключится и останавливается, потому что время подключение истекло. Ноутбук покдключен к роутуру, а ПК к роутуру через провод.
